# Paper fold in React

Tags: reactjs, animation

I have been exploring best way to achieve a paperfold effect on a React component.

I would like to know (from a React architecture perspective) whether using Paperfold JS (http://felixniklas.com/paperfold/) is a reasonable approach to getting the effect or whether it is best done without bringing in external (non-React) libraries?

Answer (score 2):

React operates on the Virtual DOM concept. Whatever change you wish to make on UI, depending on certain criteria React does that on the Virtual DOM and applies only the changes to the actual DOM after comparing both. But Most animation libraries work by directly changing the DOM node directly which is not the way of React. So I would say such practices are kind of antipatterns to React flow and the performance and flexibility which we expect from a React application may get affected due to those.

Comment: Do you have any direction as to how I might approach it in React or even better existing React components I could use (I have searched for days with no luck.). I did find this great implementation but it's for React Native and IOS only on top (https://github.com/jmurzy/react-native-foldview). I am exploring React Transition Group and Popmotion. Not sure if that's the right way?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jmurzy/7k1rc47h/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=7k1rc47h

Here's the animation which you should follow for each card. (Found this one from the link you shared). Adding the animation for each card and adding certain animation-delay to each card will give you the effect unfolding effect.

Comment: Does this seem like a sound implementation - https://codepen.io/YukiyaSassa/pen/rDmkb ?

Comment: That's a great example since it's done without JS. Please use that if that serves the purpose.